# Scaling WPF Window for Printing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Good Evening,

I am working on a small WPF app in VS2017 which uses c#. Its essentially just to make calculations for my workers in the field. I have everything built and tested, however, I am running into an issue when it comes to printing the results. I have scoured the corners of the internet and have gotten as far as getting the print dialog box to open and even print to PDF. The issue i am having is that when it prints, it is in full scale. I just need to be able to scale the app window to 80-90% of its size and then print. i will add the code and see if i am just overlooking something.

```
    private void InvokePrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)

        {

            //get selected printer capabilities

            System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);



            //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual

            double scale = Math.Min((ActualWidth*.9),ActualHeight);



            //get the size of the printer page

            Size sz = new Size((Width*.9), ActualHeight);



            //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.

            this.Measure(sz);

            this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0,0), sz));



            //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.

            printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Offset Calculations");
```

[What it is printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XetjI.png)

[What I want to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqu1B.png)

Comment: You could try to use `ViewBox` as the root element in the window.

Answer (score 0):

add reference to ReachFramework.dll 4.0

```
        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        if ((bool)dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault()) {
            //switch landscape
            dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;

            //get selected printer capabilities
            System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = dlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(dlg.PrintTicket);

            //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
            double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /  this.ActualHeight);

            //Transform the Visual to scale
            this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

            //get the size of the printer page
            Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

            //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
            this.Measure(sz);
            this.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point((int)capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, (int)capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

            //show the print dialog
            dlg.PrintVisual(this, "MyDoc_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
        }
```